# Reducing adjective clauses

Tags: sentence-construction

The person who will come tomorrow is the chairman of the committee.

```
  (1)The person to come tomorrow...
```

The book which will be sold tomorrow costs £10.20.

```
  (2)The book to be sold tomorrow...
```

Are the above reduced clauses correct? If not, please show me how to reduce them.

Answer (score 1):

> The person who will come tomorrow is the chairman of the committee.

"The person coming tomorrow ..."  ("The person to come tomorrow ..." is also fine, although not something I would personally say)

> The book which will be sold tomorrow costs £10.20.

"The book to be sold ..."

You definitely have the right idea.  If you're looking to remove words then the gerund form of the verb is useful for the active voice, and the infinitive is useful for the passive voice.

More examples:

> The cake which will be eaten after dinner tomorrow ...
>
> The cake to be eaten ...

.

> The woman who will make all the costumes
>
> The woman making all the costumes ...

Comment: I love your answer the most

Comment: Can I say '' The cake being eaten'' instead 'the cake to be taken''?

Comment: @AbuNaimMuhammedKalil yes, I think you can.  "The costumes being used in tonight's performance are made out of flowers and candy floss."  I think it depends on context, so you might want to be careful about using it indiscriminately until you can see an example of a native using it.